# Easier way to run a Java application from Maven?

Tags: java, maven

If I have understood correctly, I need to type this to run my project from maven:

```
mvn compile
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.foo.bar.blah.Main"
```

Is there a way I can make this simpler? Optimally I would like to just do

```
mvn run
```

Answer (score 6):

1) Create a new profile called "run" (or another name of your choice)

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>run</id>
```

2) Set the profile's default goal to "verify" (or you can choose "install", choosing a phase after compile will ensure that the code will automatically be compiled before running the class)

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>run</id>
      <build>
        <defaultGoal>verify</defaultGoal>
```

3) Add the exec-maven-plugin to this profile (see [this](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/)), but configure it to run in the 'verify' phase.

```
   <execution>  
    <phase>test</phase>
```

4) You can now run your class using the following:

```
mvn -Prun
```

Answer (score 5):

A little more configuration, a little less command line parameters ;-)

using the very same [exec:java plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html), you can configure your task in the pom.xml, then execute it in a simpler fashion by mapping your goal to the run step of the lifecycle, like [this example](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/) shows.

Comment: Saw that one, but as far as I can see, that would mean I would have to add it to one of the existing steps. Think they used the test step there, and yeah... When I test I want to test, not run :p

Comment: And yes, I'd prefer more config over more command-line parameters. Writing config I can do once and be done ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As the above example shows, you can wrap that plugin into a separate profile. Take a look at the [3rd solution](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no `(as far as I know). If you ahve a web application you could use [Jetty](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jetty-maven-plugin/usage.html) plugin to run it doing:

`mvn jetty:run`

but for standalone apps, you need the exec plugin.